# My Macbook Air fan is really loud

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

My fan is running really loud. I have tried resetting the SMC and it didn't work. I have no applications running and my mac is not hot. If you have any idea what is wrong please help me!

Comment: Is your Mac's fan always running with loud? or it varies while boot?

Comment: So what you are saying is that it sounds like it is running at high revolutions per minute (RPM's)?

Comment: It is always running, unless I shut it down. And yes, I believe its running at high rpm's

Comment: Try cleaning out your fans, I recently did that to my MacBook Pro, whole things runs quieter and cooler now. It's incredible how much dust gets in there...

Comment: You might find [this app](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If the SMC reset did not work it seems likely it could be a hardware problem. I would guess it's going into a fail safe mode causing the fans to always run full speed. This could happen if a temperature sensor malfunctioned , I would recommend taking the system into an Apple Authorized Service provider.